# Stop the windows search bar (aka microsoft edge search bar tray icon) from auto-launching / starting at startup

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, microsoft-edge, notification-area

On a recent windows 10 update this Microsoft Edge tray icon appeared:

[[image: Tray icon]

Clicking it opens this search bar that says "Search the web or type a URL":

[image: Search bar]

[Windows 10 forums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0DVW.png) suggest disabling the auto-launch setting. I did this but then a month later (and presumably after another update) this setting was ignored and the tray icon and search bar came back.

Does anyone know how to permanently disable it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My own solution:

### Disable it

#### A. Registry

1. Start menu > type "registry" > right click > run Registry Editor as admin (or open it if you don't have this option)
2. In the input field at the top, under the menu bar, paste this:

   `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge`
3. Do this twice: Right click > New > DWORD (32 bit value).

   Now: right click > rename each to:

   `WebWidgetIsEnabledOnStartup`

   `WebWidgetAllowed`
4. Make sure each DWORD's value is 0 (it should be by default)

#### B. Double kill: Group policy

1. Download the file `MicrosoftEdgePolicyTemplates.cab` at the [edge enterprise page](https://aka.ms/EdgeEnterprise) and extract the contents. [This](https://msedge.sf.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/41bed53b-c6e0-4b79-bf1f-bd33844b7aea/MicrosoftEdgePolicyTemplates.cab) is the direct link I got (may not still work).
2. Extract the cab and then the zip and find the folder `admx`. It should be at `(extract folder)\MicrosoftEdgePolicyTemplates\windows\admx\`
3. Copy all the `.admx` files to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`. Then back in the admx folder find your language folder (e.g. `en-US`). Copy all the `.adml` files there to the corresponding language folder at `PolicyDefinitions`
4. Start menu > type: `gpedit.msc` > open as admin (or just open).
5. Click: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > All settings.
   Then (menu bar) View > Filter options > Filter for word(s) > input `WebWidgetAllowed`
6. Filter. Microsoft Edge > Disable the setting for Computer and User

[Source](https://blog.bn-l.net/posts/07-05-23-Edge-search-bar.html)

Comment: note: downvotes on Stack Exchange are not to be mean to people. see [/help/why-vote](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Please note that both these registry keys are now deprecated according to Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies

The only workaround I know is to have a process that launches on login that monitors for all instances of msedge.exe and kills them.  It's amazing how they have reverted to the nonsense of Internet Explorer after adopting chromium for edge.